# Select minimum row and return the column name using R

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
             A=c(2,4,6,7,8,9,2),
             B=c(3,2,3,6,6,4,3),
             C=c(1,2,3,4,6,3,2))
```

I want to create a variable named 'type', the value of the 'type' variable is the A,B,C's column name which has the min value. And if A=B=C, fill A, if B=C

So the output should be:

```
df <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
             A=c(2,4,6,7,8,9,2),
             B=c(3,2,3,6,6,4,3),
             C=c(1,2,3,4,6,3,2),
          type=c(C,B,B,C,B,C,A))
```

Comment: Your code for `df` in input as well output does not work.

Comment: it is correct now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `max.col` which returns the column number of maximum value in each row but since we want min value here we can negate it. In case of a tie first minimum value will be returned this can be specified via `ties.method`.

```
names(df)[-1][max.col(-df[-1], ties.method = 'first')]
#[1] "C" "B" "B" "C" "B" "C" "A"
```

`-1` here is to ignore the first column i.e `PATIENT_ID`.

We can also use `apply` :

```
names(df[-1])[apply(df[-1], 1, which.min)]
```

---

You can select only specific columns by :

```
cols <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
cols[max.col(-df[cols], ties.method = 'first')]
```

Or

```
cols[apply(df[cols], 1, which.min)]
```

Comment: Actually, I also have many other variables in my dataset. How can I only limit to the variable A,B,C? Thank you.

Comment: @NewYorkCrosser Updated the answer.